# Android: unable to get orientation of photo shared from Google+

Tags: android, image, android-intent, orientation

I am sharing a photo from Google+ with my app but I am unable to determine the orientation of the image. That is some images come out with the correct orientation and some are at right angles but I cannot find any metadata that distinguishes between the two.  I have tried using the ExifInterface and querying the content resolver without success. I think the ExifInterface approach will only work for images which are local to the device. Querying the ContentResolver only seems to return the name, size and mime-type.

Needless to say GMail and Snapseed handle it perfectly.

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

System.out.println("image-uri: " + imageUri);
InputStream is = resolver.openInputStream(imageUri);
BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
is.close();
System.out.println("got image dims: " + dbo.outWidth + "x" + dbo.outHeight);

ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath());
int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
System.out.println("orientation from ExifInterface: " + orientation);

// print out all the metadata we can find
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println("col[" + i + "] name:" + cursor.getColumnName(i) + " type:" + cursor.getType(i) + " str:" + cursor.getString(i));
  }
}
cursor.close();
```

which generates the following output:

- image-uri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2FBzkgMI32pI5sx0LWvQW521i0-KoPn3mDaz1pD8O0MTU5%3Ds0-d
- got image dims: 40x40
- *can't open
  '/0/https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/BzkgMI32pI5sx0LWvQW521i0-KoPn3mDaz1pD8O0MTU5=s0-d'*
- orientation from ExifInterface: 0
- col[0] name:_display_name type:3 str:image.jpg
- col[1] name:_size type:3 str:2846
- col[2] name:mime_type type:3 str:image/jpeg

As always any help would be very gratefully received.

Comment: try looking at the exif in the incorrect image and compare it with the correct ones the fastest way to do it is to open the photo using notepad

Comment: I'm not sure where to look for the Exif when the only information I have about the image is a Uri, namely: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2FBzkgMI32pI5sx0LWvQW521i0-KoPn3mDaz1pD8O0MTU5%3Ds0-d I am relying on a ContentResolver to do all the magic.